# Case-insensitive advanced search in Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I apply first example result to second example?

1) Case insensitive search result in Rails model

```
 self.where("LOWER(shop_name) like ?", "%#{search.downcase}%")
```

2) advanced search

```
shops =Shop.where("shop_name LIKE '%#{keywords}%' AND shop_city LIKE '%#{keywords2}%' AND shop_country LIKE '%#{keywords3}%' AND market_type LIKE '%#{keywords4}%'") if keywords||keywords2||keywords3||keywords4.present?
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to a SQL injection attack. Please do some research on that.

Answer (score 0):

i solve this

```
shops =Shop.where("LOWER(shop_name) LIKE '%#{keywords.downcase}%' AND LOWER(shop_city) LIKE '%#{keywords2.downcase}%' AND LOWER(shop_country) LIKE '%#{keywords3.downcase}%' AND LOWER(market_type) LIKE '%#{keywords4.downcase}%'") if keywords.downcase||keywords2.downcase||keywords3.downcase||keywords4.downcase.present?
```

please tell me this one  right or wrong

Answer (score 0):

To avoid error change your if at and of 2) replace || by &&

```
shops =Shop.where("shop_name LIKE '%#{keywords}%' AND shop_city LIKE '%#{keywords2}%' AND shop_country LIKE '%#{keywords3}%' AND market_type LIKE '%#{keywords4}%'") if keywords && keywords2 && keywords3 && keywords4
```

You may already know or you need to know this request will be very slow to process

Answer (score 0):

I split your code to be sure what you really want

```
query = ''
query << 'LOWER(shop_name) LIKE :keywords '
query << 'AND LOWER(shop_city) LIKE :keywords2 '
query << 'AND LOWER(shop_country) LIKE :keywords3 '
query << 'AND LOWER(market_type) LIKE :keywords4'

shops = Shop.where(
  query,
  keywords: keywords.downcase || '',
  keywords2: keywords2.downcase || '',
  keywords3: keywords3.downcase || '',
  keywords4: keywords4.downcase || '',
) unless keywords.blank? && keyword2.blank? && keywords3.blank? && keywords4.blank?
```